# Jquery Kendo GRID add datasource method

Tags: jquery, kendo-grid

I have used jquery kendo grid for one my project and it is working like a charm.

But the only problem is when i try to add a new record to the kendo grid it is always adding that new  record at last place i mean at last row ..

can we have any option to add a new record at first place . This is what i have in my add function

```
var tr = $(e.target).closest("tr");
 var dataElem = this.dataItem(tr);
 XGrid.gridControl.getKendoObject().dataSource.add(dataElem);
```

This is always adding  the dataelement as a last row in the XGrid. Can we add the same  as a first row ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Insert method `dataSource.insert(position, dataobject)`

```
dataSource.insert(0,{
      id: currentId,
      done: false,
      description: $todo.val()
    });
```

Here is a demo **[Adding a new Item](http://jsfiddle.net/gwrouek2/)**

Another way around.

'Kendo grid data source is an `array of objects`(every row data is an object)

So here you can use the Use [`unshift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift). It's like [`push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), except it adds elements to the beginning of the array instead of the end.

```
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4];
    array.unshift(0);

console.log(array ); // [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: Thanks man !! used below one and it worked 

XGrid.gridControl.getKendoObject().dataSource.insert(0,dataElem);